# Convert Variables into Array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have a problem converting variables into array.
I am running foreach loop to get values from my multidimensional array $images. $images array contains image name eg: "Item Blue.png" or "Item Light Oak.png" and id of each image.

```
foreach ($images['images'] as $image) {
    $image_name = explode(" ", substr_replace($image->filename ,"",-4));
    if(!empty($image_name[2])) {
        $colour = ucfirst($image_name[1] . " " . $image_name[2]);
    }
    else {
        $colour = ucfirst($image_name[1]);
    }
}
```

$colour variable is giving me Color name and $image->id can give me image id.

I would like to build $colors array with above variables that it would look like this:

```
$colors = array(
    'Blue' => 1620,
    'Green' => 1467,
);
```

Kind of like this:

```
$colors = array(
    '$colour' => $image->id,
);
```

I have no idea how to do this and I will appreciate any help to give me at least some directions.

Thanks

Comment: can you show us some sample input and output ?

Comment: print_r($images);
Array
(
    [images] => Array
        (
            [1620] => ProductImage Object
                (
                    [filename] => Brancepeth Blue.png
                    [id] => 1620
                )
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty straightforward ... Two things to do:

First initialize the colors array outside of your foreach:

```
 $colors=array();   //<-- add this
 foreach ($images['images'] as $image) {
     $image_name = explode(" ", substr_replace($image->filename ,"",-4));
     ...
```

then just add one line after the if/else, still inside your foreach loop that will insert a new item into the $colors array.

```
    ...
    else {
        $colour = ucfirst($image_name[1]);
    }
    $colors[$colour]=$image->id;  //<-- add this
}
```

This will create a colors array with contents like what you're looking for.  I'm assuming that there is an 'id' key in the $image iterator.  Did you need to create one?

All that said, you're not checking for these problems:

1. color names with spaces, like 'light oak'
2. item names with spaces like 'large item light oak.png'
3. duplicate colors with different IDs

Hope that helps

Comment: small problem  
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Blue] => 1620 ) [1] => Array ( [Green] => 1621 ) [2] => Array ( [Red] => 1622 ) [3] => Array ( [White] => 1623 ) [4] => Array ( [Bronze Left] => 1670 ) [5] => Array ( [Bronze Right] => 1671 ) [6] => Array ( [Chrome Left] => 1672 ) [7] => Array ( [Chrome Right] => 1673 ) )

Comment: edited the answer.  Apologies for the confusion.  The line that adds the items to the array was wrong.

Comment: filename will be consistent and I might work on that later, here problem is with the code, array have there own key now. The key should be colour.

Comment: Hah, and I accidentally edited my reply to your reply, not seeing your new reply.  I had a mis-read your desired output .. the answer was updated-- just change the line to read: $colors[$colour]=$image->id;